# OpenCL stops running only while call in a loop

Tags: c++, visual-studio, kernel, opencl

My code breaks when i try to loop the data back to the kernel function, after a few iteration it stop working, giving only 0 as an answer, does someone knows why? If i loop the whole method that call the kernel it works but is much slower

```
cl_mem *ptrInput = &Pressure_BUFF;
cl_mem *ptrOutput = &Pressure_OUT_BUFF;

for(int i = 0; i<Interaction_per_frame; i++){

    clSetKernelArg(kernel_2, 4, sizeof(Pressure_BUFF), ptrInput);
    clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue_2, kernel_2, 1, NULL,&work_units_per_kernel, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    clFinish(queue_2);//Terminar de calcular

    cl_mem *ptrTpm = ptrInput;
    ptrInput = ptrOutput;
    ptrOutput = ptrTpm;

}

clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue_2, Pressure_OUT_BUFF, CL_TRUE, 0,sizeof(Pressure), Pressure, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: Use `clEnqueueCopyBuffer` in place of cl_mem juggling.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just change the input memory buffer leaving the output untouched.
Otherwise the data has same input as output.

The cleanest way to do this is with 2 kernels, so you don't need to call setargs and finish everytime.

```
//Create 2 buffers, A and B
bufA = clCreateBuffer(...);
bufB = clCreateBuffer(...);

//Create 2 kernels with same parameters
kernelAB = clCreateKernel(...);
kernelBA = clCreateKernel(...);

//Set one to input A output B, and the other in reverse
clSetKernelArgs(kernelAB, in, bufferA);
clSetKernelArgs(kernelAB, out, bufferB);
clSetKernelArgs(kernelBA, in, bufferB);
clSetKernelArgs(kernelBA, out, bufferA);

for(int i = 0; i<Interaction_per_frame; i++){
    clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue_2, i%2 ? kernelBA : kernelAB, 1, NULL,&work_units_per_kernel, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);    
}

clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue_2, Interaction_per_frame%2 ? bufferB : bufferA, CL_TRUE, 0,sizeof(Pressure), Pressure, 0, NULL, NULL);
```